# Make doted lines in r-statictic legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

I´ve tried to do a legend to a plot with for different lines. This lines most all be black so i have used lwd and lty to separate them from each other. It looks great, but then I want to make a legend that explains which line is which. It works fine for the `lwd` lines but when I´m trying to do the same for the `lty` lines I get the error message:

```
>Error in segments(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...) : 
  invalid line type: must be length 2, 4, 6 or 8
```

The command I've used for plotting the legend is

```
legend('topleft', legend= c("Red light","Blue light") , lwd=c("1","2"))
```

This is for the first two so I have tried the command:

```
legend('topleft', legend= c("Green light","Orange light") , lwd=c("1","2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but does this help:

```
plot(0, 0)
legend('topleft', legend= c("Red light","Blue light"), lwd=1:2, lty=1:2)
```